Next UI project showing blank page after build
I have setup react project with nextui-cli, with react and vite.
when serving locally its working fine.
but after building the app, and then lading the index.html to the browser with flag --allow-file-access-from-files,
Then expectation is the UI should work, but I am getting a blank page with no console error all the assets are loading files (I set base path to "./" in vite config).
but, a normal vite project with react works, as expected.

what is the issue here?
Edit:-
The problem seems to be with the react-router. I am developing the UI for the Chrome extension and I need to serve the UI from the file protocol,
but, it's showing a blank page.

After digging around, we need to use hashRouter to make it work, instead of browser router.
